# How to automatically enforce RAM limits for individual application?

Tags: linux, firefox, memory, memory-limit, memory-usage

RAM usage of both Firefox and TOR browser (based on Firefox) is really getting out of hand, I therefore need to set a permanent limit on both applications. For every new instance of either browser incl. child processes, this limit should be enforced automatically. How can this be done in Linux Mint Debian Edition 4? Could this be done by modifying `/etc/security/limits.conf`? And will Firefox "know" when it's reaching the limit and free up resources or will it just crash?

As an alternative to an OS-enforced hard limit, would it be possible to trigger `about:memory > Free memory > GC/CC/Minimize memory usage` in Firefox automatically whenever the memory limit is reached, allowing Firefox to handle this on its own?

I need a "set and forget" solution. The only other option is to abandon Firefox altogether, since Mozilla seems not to be willing to solve RAM issues any more (see myriad bug reports).

Comment: Generally firefox will have a one or more tabs crash when it runs out of memory.   I expeimented with `ulimit -m` but it seemed to have no effect.

Comment: @Jasen: This means that triggering Firefox's own memory cleaner is the best way to go. Can this be done with via a terminal command? Or does Firefox have an API that interfaces with Python?